# How to replace a few of the node circles in a force directed layout with functional javascript toggle switches?

Tags: javascript, togglebutton, force-layout

I am trying to model complicated harnesses/cabling configurations using a force directed layout. Most harnesses have lots of connector ends which looks just like a typical force directed layout.

I have been experimented with examples on how to replace circles with rectangles or simple images. I am looking for something more complicated such as a 2 state toggle switch to locally track a configuration changes (mated or demated).

I chose the input button below because it appeared that individual buttons can be specifically named for tracking states.

I have been attempting to combine these:

```
<input class="toggleable-button" name="" type="checkbox" checked value="0" />
```

```
  var node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("toggleable-button", "nodes")
    .selectAll("g")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
```

Most nodes are displayed by a circle or text won't need to change, but the states of toggles switches will change during hardware integration. I would like to eventually track this set toggle switch states in a JSON file so that they could be used to initialized the start of the next session of changes. I first need some idea how to replace specific nodes.

Comment: I'm having a hard time visualizing what you are going for. Could you maybe put a small example on CodePen or jsfiddle and link to it?

Comment: Thank you for identifying how I might provide better information. The codepen link below shows what I am looking for: https://codepen.io/BeeWhyZzz/pen/wZJZMO